# C++/WINAPI find out whether program is outputting to cmd or bash

Tags: c++, bash, winapi, cmd

I am currently writing a toy-compiler in my free-time in C++ and I am using Visual Studio do to my development work. Although I am on a Windows System, I have replaced my standard Console with the msysgit bash version. Now, I am trying to implement color-coded error messages which work fine in bash, but don't work in cmd. I am coloring my text using the bash color keys like \x1B[0m etc... Now, the problem is that when the compiler outputs error messages to the console, someone using cmd.exe as their default console will see a garbled mess of seemingly random letters making the error message hard to decipher. One solution I found to be working is completely disabeling color coding on Windows systems which works, but is kind of inconvinient. I am looking for a way to find out whether the console to which the compiler is outputting to is cmd.exe or bash.exe. I have looked through MSDN and didn't find anything particulary useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/120487/how-can-i-determine-a-cmd-exes-parent-process

Comment: You can take a snapshot of all running processes by calling [Process32First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834.aspx). Iterating over all [PROCESSENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) structures until you find one where *th32ProcessID* matches your process' ID. You then have the parent process' ID through its *th32ParentProcessID* member.

Comment: I would suggest a simpler approach - implement an input parameter, such as a command-line switch or environment variable, that tells the compiler which output format to use, and then bash (and bash-compatible shells) can enable the colorized output if the user wants it.